# PHP Success message after submit

Tags: php, html, web, echo

I'm using a simple php code to send mail from my website

```
    <?php 

    $headers ="From:<$from>\n";
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f$from");


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "contato@pedrogps.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thanks for your message";
    ?>
```

when i submit the email, it brings to another page (mail.php) with the "thanks for your message" message.

What can i do to display this message inside my html page without switching pages.

Comment: Learn about Ajax.

Comment: You should Post your data via ajax, send mail in the background and then on success, show the success message via jquery.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, i don't know ajax....

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the webpage to load, when submitting, you'll need some JavaScript.

```
<form id="mailForm">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    $('#mailForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $('#mailForm').serialize();
        var url = "mail.php";
        var posting = $.post(url, formData);

        posting.done(function(data) {
            $("#result").append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Remember to load the jQuery library, read more about jQuery here: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/. Read more about the jQuery.post() here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

If you do not care if the webpage loads, when submitting, then you can easily use the `include` function in PHP.

```
<form id="mailForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" name="mail" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="result">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['mail']))
        {
            include("mail.php");
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Maybe you should check some more things than only the `$_POST['mail']` is set, but you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways one is use AJAX and another one:

1. make form action empty like

   ```
    <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
   ```
2. before form start or top of the page write this php code:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST)){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "contato@pedrogps.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
       echo "Thanks for your message"; // store this msg in a variable and display wherever you required to echo
   ```

   }